# Is it stupid to put used acid into a pool after cleaning the chlorinator?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, electrolysis, water-treatment

I have a salt pool, and when the chlorinator salts up with calcium, I clean it with a diluted acidic solution.

What happens to the acidic solution after the reaction happens? I.e., does the pH change?

Would it be stupid to put the used solution into the pool afterwards? Am I correct in thinking the following sentence? "We are trying to get the calcium out of the pool, but putting it back in just means the chlorinator has to get it out again." Or, it is stupid for a different reason, e.g. the acidic solution is too weak after the reaction anyway?

Comment: You put more calcium to the pool. If this reflects on the interval between cleaning up the chlorinator isn't sure.  The real concentration in the pool should not be really affected, nor the pH

Answer (score 0):

The bicarbonate buffer capacity of the pool  water probably would deal with the remaining acid, but the pH would IMHO get lower.

But returning calcium to pool is not wise, as it will cause calcium accumulation and progressively shortening periods of calcium precipitation.